# Axios catch error Request failed with status code 404

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I'm testing a login component that uses Axios. I tried mocking Axios with `axios-mock-adapter`, but when I run the tests, it still errors out with:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

How do I properly mock Axios in my tests?

### login.spec.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Login from '../../src/components/global/login/Login.vue';
import Raven from "raven-js";
import jQuery from 'jquery'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import router from '../../src/router'
var axios = require('axios');
var MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');

describe('Login.vue', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let componentInstance;
  let mock;
  beforeEach(() => {
    global.requestAnimationFrame = setImmediate,
    mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    wrapper = shallowMount(Login, {
      router,
      $: jQuery,
      attachToDocument: true,
      mocks: {
        $t: () => { },
        Raven: Raven,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          email: '',
          password: '',
        }
      }
    })
    componentInstance = wrapper.vm;
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    mock.reset()
  })

  it('calls `axios()` with `endpoint`, `method` and `body`', async () => {
    const formData = {
      email: 'example@gmail.com',
      password: '111111'
    };

    let fakeData = { data: "fake response" }
    mock.onPost(`${process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL}/login/`, formData).reply(200, fakeData);

    wrapper.vm.email = 'example@gmail.com';
    wrapper.vm.password = '111111';
    wrapper.vm.doSigninNormal()
  })
})
```

### Login.vue

```js
doSigninNormal() {
  const formData = {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
  };
  this.$v.$touch()
  if (this.$v.$invalid ) {
    this.loading = false;
    this.emailLostFocus = true;
    this.passwordLostFocus = true;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:110}, 'slow')

  } else {
    axios.post("/login", formData, {
      headers: { "X-localization": localStorage.getItem("lan") }
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.data.result) {
        if (res.data.errors) {
          for (var i = 0; i < res.data.errors.length; i++) {
            this.$toaster.error(res.data.errors[i].message);
            if (
              res.data.errors[0].message == "Your email is not yet verified"
            ) {
              this.showVerificationLinkButton = true;
            }
            if (res.data.errors[i].field === "email") {
              this.$toaster.error(res.data.errors[i].message);
            }
            if (res.data.errors[i].field === "password") {
              this.$toaster.error(res.data.errors[i].message);
            }
          }
        }

        this.loading = false;
        this.$v.$reset();
      } else {
        this.loading = false;
        Raven.setUserContext({
          email: res.data.user.email,
          id: res.data.user.id
        });
        this.$store.dispatch("login", res);
        this.$v.$reset();
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
       console.log('catch', err);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: is the api you are calling a get or a post call and whether it exists please check it

Comment: @AKASHPANDEY yes, it is exists. i want to call function and then call api(inside the function) and get response. 
wrapper.vm.doSigninNormal()

Comment: You want to call the real API in the tests? Or you want to provide a mock as axios, and fake the server with it?

Comment: @Sergeon i want to call function. inside the function it call real api.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Testing wrong login URL

The root problem is the test code sets up `axios-mock-adapter` on a different URL than actually used in `Login.vue`, so the request is not stubbed:

```
// login.spec.js:
mock.onPost(`${process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL}/login/`, formData).reply(200, fakeData)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// Login.vue
axios.post("/login", formData)
            ^^^^^^
```

The fix is to make the test code use the same URL (i.e., `/login`):

```
// login.spec.js
mock.onPost("/login", formData).reply(200, fakeData)
```

#### Need to await axios.post()

The unit test isn't awaiting the `POST` request, so the test wouldn't be able to reliably verify calls or responses (without a hack).

The fix is to update `doSigninNormal()` to return the `axios.post()` promise to allow callers to await the result:

```
// Login.vue
doSigninNormal() {
  return axios.post(...)
}

// login.spec.js
await wrapper.vm.doSigninNormal()
expect(mock.history.post.length).toBe(1)
```

#### Verifying login result

To verify the result, you could declare a local data prop to hold the login result 1️⃣, update `doSigninNormal()` to process the response (which is mocked with `fakeData` in the test), capturing the result 2️⃣. Then, just check that data property after awaiting `doSignInNormal()`.

```
// Login.vue
data() {
  return {
    ...
    result: '' 1️⃣
  }
}
methods: {
  doSignInNormal() {
    return axios.post(...)
            .then(resp => this.result = resp.data.result) 2️⃣
  }
}

// login.spec.js
const result = await wrapper.vm.doSigninNormal()
expect(result).toBe(fakeData.result)
expect(wrapper.vm.result).toBe(fakeData.result)
```

[image: Edit Mocking Axios calls with axios-mock-adapter]

Answer (score 2):

### Mocking Axios:

There are two easy ways to mock axios so your tests don't perform real http requests and use a mock object instead:

#### set axios as a component property:

```
import axios from 'axios`;
Vue.component({
  data() {
    return {
      axios,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    makeApiCall() {
      return this.axios.post(...)
    }
  }
})
```

So you can inject a mock in your tests easily:

```
it('test axions', function() {
  const post = jest.fn();
  const mock = {
    post,
  }
  // given 
  const wrapper = shallowMount(myComponent, {
    data: {
      axios: mock,
    }
  });

  // when
  wrapper.vm.makeApiCall();

  // then
  expect(post).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I think this is the most straightforward way.

#### Use a plugin to inject axios in every component

You can setup a plugin like [vue-plugin-axios](https://github.com/yugasun/vue-axios-plugin) to inject axios automatically into every component, like:

```
  makeApiCall(){
    this.$axios.post(...)
  }
```

Without the need to explicitly declare it in `data`.

Then in your test, instead of passing the mock as part of `data`, you pass it as part of `mocks`, which is the way `vue-test-utils` deals with global injections:

```
it('test axions', function() {
  const post = jest.fn();
  const mock = {
    post,
  }
  // given 
  const wrapper = shallowMount(myComponent, {
    mocks: {
      $axios: mock,
    }
  });

  // when
  wrapper.vm.makeApiCall();

  // then
  expect(post).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This is how to mock axios calls to prevent call real axios and perform real http request.

### Configuring mock behavior and access call parameters

With `jest.fn` you can setup a mock function to return a specific object, like:

`const post = jest.fn( () => ({status: 200, response: ...}) )`

You can also access the parameters to the call via `hasBeenCalledWith' method, or more complex stuff via` mock.calls` ([more info here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions)):

`expect(post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedParams)`.

So, your final test should be like the following I think:

```
it('calls axios() with endpoint, method and body',async (done) => {

  // given
  const formData = { email: 'example@gmail.com', password: '111111' };
  const fakeResponse = {response: "fake response"};
  const email = 'example@gmail.com';
  const uri = 'somepath/login/'; // I dont think you can access Vue process env variables in the tests, so you'll need to hardcode.
  const password = '11111';

  const post = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({status: 200}) );

  const mock = {
    post,
  }
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
    data() {
      return {
        axios: mock,
        // email,
        // password, // you could do this instead to write to wrapper.vm later
      }
    }
  });
  wrapper.vm.email = 'example@gmail.com';
  wrapper.vm.password = '111111';

  // when
  await wrapper.vm.doSigninNormal();

  // then
  expect(post).toHaveBeenCalledWith({uri, password, email});

  // or
  const calls = post.mock.calls;
  const firstParam = calls[0][0];
  
  expect(firstParam.uri).toBe(uri);
  expect(firstParam.email).toBe(email);
  expect(firstParam.password).toBe(password);

  done();

});
```

Comment: i tried so hard and the result like this 
please see the [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wJU3NV83JknVBy2js_jpcHLDaOBao77Y/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on the [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) package. It requires an instance of axios using the `.create()` method.
See here:
[creating an instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance)

In your App.js,
use:

```
import axios from "axios";
const instance = axios.create();

instance.post("http://localhost/api/user/update", {name: "Test"}, {headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer token")}});
```

Nothing needs to be changed in the tests though.

I got the hint from tests of [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter).

An example of such is:
[post test](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter/blob/master/test/basics.spec.js#L274)

Comment: An instance is not actually required. That just happens to be the way their tests are setup.

Answer (score 1):

> If axios instance adapter(xhr or http) taked over by axios-mock-adapter, there will have an error with bad baseURL config like this:

```
{baseURL:'/for/bar'}
```

If we send an request like:

```
get('/api/v1/exampleService')
```

The last http request will become

```
'http://host:port/for/bar/for/bar/api/v1/exampleService'
```

Because mock-adapter take over axios default adapter,  apis that not match mock rules will be pass through, and be processed by default adapter , both these adapter select logic go through here（core/dispatchRequest.js）:

```
if (config.baseURL && !isAbsoluteURL(config.url)) { 
   config.url = combineURLs(config.baseURL, config.url);
}
```

Thus, if you use mock, please use full url starts with http://